# How to Install KAFKA Inside Virtual Box Have Hortonworks

Tags: apache-kafka, hortonworks-data-platform

I installed `Oracle Virtual Machine and inside that did Hortonworks` 
set up.

Now I am trying to install Kafka in it. 
When I fetch file using wget it got installed.

How can I see in which location the file saved.
And how to call it from Virtual Box.
How can I see all dependencies has install which required for KAFKA like

```
Java, scala,zookeeper
```

Please help
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you're using wget when Ambari should be installing components for you.

Hortonworks installs all libraries under `/usr/hdp/current`

There should be a Kafka folder there

However, it's recommended you use Ambari to configure those resources, and all Kafka CLI tools should be on your path already